# http.server (SimpleHTTPServer) serve file.html instead of dir (using cmd)

Tags: python, simplehttpserver, http.server

Is it possible to serve not a index of a directory but rather an `html` file using Python `SimpleHTTPServer` on path `'/'`?

Having directory with one file `login.html` serves a directory index on path `'/'`.

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 7800
```

[image: screenshot]

I want a content of `login.html` on `'/'`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SimpleHTTPServer` (or `http.server` in Python3) will serve a directory *unless* that directory contains a file called `index.html`, in which case it will serve that instead.

So just rename `login.html` to `index.html` and it should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

By default http server looks for index.html file and loads it. Otherwise it will serve the directory structure.

You can extend SimpleHTTPServer and write your own class with proper routing. I would prefer this.

But alternatively you could also add a redirect in index.html.

```html
<html>
<body>
    <!-- redirect on load -->
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            window.location.href = "login.html";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```